# bash, execute "edmEventSize" command but it is not found when i tyoe bash script.sh

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, edmx

i hava a file in which using the command "edmEventSize" i can
extract a piece of information of that file (it is a number) 
but know i have 700 files on which i have to execute that command
and i am trying to do it on a bash script but i cannot event do it for just
one file since i get "edmEventSize command not found", i already look for 
more information but since i am new at bash i can not solve this task
Thank you in advanced

this is my script

```
#/usr/bin/env sh
for i in {1..700}; 
do
FILE="Py6_BstoJpsiKs0_7TeV_RECO_Run-0${i}.root"

edmEventSize... $FILE.root > salida${i}.log
done

head *.log | grep "^File" | cut -f4 > a.txt 
rm *.log
```

Comment: `edmEventSize` isn't in your `$PATH`. Use the full pathname to the command.

Comment: Try specifying the entire path for the `edmEventSize` executable.

Comment: Also, there's no need for all those `.log` files. Pipe the output of `edmEventSize` directly to `head | grep '^File'`, and redirect the whole loop to `a.txt`.

Comment: i am sorry but i do not know the full pathname to the command, since when i type in the terminal "edmEventSize name_of_file" it gives me the info i want

Comment: try `which edmEventSize`

Comment: i try to do it in a bash script for just one file:

Comment: Please don't change your questions from its original meaning. Please don't ask follow-up questions by editing your original question. And please don't add new questions as answers. If you have a new question, ask a new one.If you have solved your own question, please post a single answer fully answering the question you originally asked.

Comment: ok, since i saw the option of editing my question, i click on it, but it wont happen again, thanks for the advertise.

Comment: @celonilanaparticle Well, you are of course encouraged to edit your question to improve clarity or add additional details. It is just frowned upon if the *original meaning* of a question is radically changed and thus the context of the other answers is lost. As I said, if you have a new question, ask a new one.

Comment: Seriously you at least need to study basics of Bash scripting. Don't try to invent your own syntax. See [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) or [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). Also take advice from answers and don't ignore them. I provided you with a code that's already formatted cleanly but you just ignored it. And if you're actually just trying to troll grow up. Anyone can do that but many doesn't for obvious reasons - it's simply lame.

Comment: you are being rude. i am not inventing sintax, i searched a lot to solve my task (and i solved it already), i did not ignore your code, it simply did not worked for me. This is my last messagge for you, i just wanted to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone would suggest, you can simplify your script like this:

```
#/bin/bash
for i in {1..700}; do
    FILE="Py6_BstoJpsiKs0_7TeV_RECO_Run-0${i}.root"
    /path/to/EdmEventSize "$FILE.root"
done | awk -F $'\t' '/^File/{print $4}' > a.txt
```

If your files actually are in the format of `Py6_BstoJpsiKs0_7TeV_RECO_Run-####.root` maybe the command you really need is:

```
    printf -v FILE 'Py6_BstoJpsiKs0_7TeV_RECO_Run-%04d.root' "$i"
```

Comment: hello, thanks a lot four your answer, the thing is i do not know the path of the command "edmEventSize", when i type in the terminal "edmEventSize name_of_file.root" it gives me the information i need but i want to implement this command to a bash file

Comment: Are you actually able to run the command `edmEventSize` even when you're not doing it in a bash script? Try `which edmEventSize` or `type -P edmEventSize`. That would give your path if the binary does exist in any directory specified by `$PATH`.

Comment: hi KONSOLEBOX , yes i am able to run the command edmEventSize, if i write in ehe file directory edmEventSize+name_of_file i get the info i need, but since now i have 700 files , that why i want to included in a bash script

Comment: If that's the case `which edmEventSize` or `type -P edmEventSize` *in a normal shell terminal* and -not- on any other places like other scripting languages should give the path to it. e.g. `$ which edmEventSize`

Comment: i just saw that the command works adding -v "edmEventSize name_of_file" but the output file "salida.txt" is empty, y put the code in the page

Comment: Where did you add `-v "edmEventSize name_of_file"`? I'm not really sure if you know what you're doing. And sorry I don't think I can help with misleading info. And have you tried `which` or `type`?

Comment: the thing is i am working with certain software that includes that command and yes, i tried -which- and -type-. i wrote "edmEventSize -v name_of_file" and it works, it shows the info i need. now i need to know how to save that information into a txt file (actually i just need a number that is in a line of that info). Sorry for not explaining myself, but thanks for your time and help

Comment: @celonilanaparticle It would be better to update your question with current codes used and current output - include errors so people can analyze it more easily and find the problem to your code. The more information like output when not in script, etc., the more it would help.

Comment: how do i do that? i add my new code as a new answer to my question?